# concatenate inputs in verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

In my module I am taking two input 8-bits.

```
mymodule(input clk, input [7:0] AS_1,input [7:0] AS_2, output [7:0] AS)
```

Now I want to create a container that will keep both inputs, I mean I want to join them in a single one. I want to do something like that:

```
reg [15:0] JOIN = AS_1 and AS_2 ---> all their bits should be arranged in a single container
```

But I don't know whether it should be a reg type or wire or something else, because I'll need to make other operations with that JOIN

Any help, advise or suggestion would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be reg or wire, you assign them slightly different but the result is the same:

```
wire [15:0] join;
assign join = {AS_1, AS_2}; //concatenation operator
```

or:

```
reg [15:0] join;
always @* begin
    join = {AS_1, AS_2};
end
```

In either case you can use the value of `join` exactly the same.

Comment: Is it the same if we could assign like join[15:8]=AS_1; and assign join[7:0]=AS_2;  ?

Comment: @bledi you are correct, the same as `assign join[15:8]=AS_1;` and `assign join[7:0]=AS_2;`